# Font in ToC entries

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, tocloft

I used

```
{\sffamily\tableofcontents}
```

to change the font from Times New Roman to sans serif in my table of contents. Then I used

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip6pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip6pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip6pt}
```

in preamble to increase the space between ToC entries. But I found that all the entries in ToC (except chapter name) changed back to Times New Roman. How can I fix this. A MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

\usepackage{tocloft}                  
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip6pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip6pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip6pt}

\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

{\sffamily\tableofcontents}

\chapter{QWERTYUIOP}              
\section{XYZXYZXYZXYZ}
\chapter{QWERTYUIOP}              
\section{XYZXYZXYZXYZ}
\chapter{QWERTYUIOP}              
\section{XYZXYZXYZXYZ}
\chapter{QWERTYUIOP}              
\section{XYZXYZXYZXYZ}
\subsection{xyxyzxyzxyzxyz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Can you please provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: A minimal (non-)working example would help to help.

Comment: I just added the MWE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft), you have to set the fonts for each sectional component separately. There is no over-arching font setting, since each component is placed inside a box or group with their own font-specification. It allows the ultimate specificity, even though it might not suit your generic needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip6pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip6pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip6pt}

% Adjust sectional unit title fonts in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\sffamily}

\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{QWERTYUIOP}
\section{XYZXYZXYZXYZ}
\chapter{QWERTYUIOP}
\section{XYZXYZXYZXYZ}
\chapter{QWERTYUIOP}
\section{XYZXYZXYZXYZ}
\chapter{QWERTYUIOP}
\section{XYZXYZXYZXYZ}
\subsection{xyxyzxyzxyzxyz}

\end{document}
```

Note that you'll have to set the page number fonts as well. This requires

```
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\sffamily}
```

Comment: The OP will probably also want to reset `\cfttoctitlefont`.

Comment: And `\cftXpagefont` for the page numbers. Also the chapter titles are no longer bold.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution based on `titletoc`, from the `titlesec`bundle;

```
\documentclass[fleqn, a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsmargin[1cm]{0cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\vskip12pt\bfseries\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace}
{\hspace{1.05em}}
{ \hfill\contentspage}[\vskip 6pt]

\titlecontents{section}[1em]{\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\quad\contentspage}[\vskip 4pt]

\titlecontents{subsection}[2.7em]{\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\quad\contentspage}[\vskip 3pt]

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\contentsname}{\sffamily}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter*{INTRODUCTION}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INTRODUCTION}
\chapter{QWERTYUIOP}
\section{XYZXYZXYZXYZ}
\chapter{QWERTYUIOP}
\section{XYZXYZXYZXYZ}
\chapter{QWERTYUIOP}
\section{XYZXYZXYZXYZ}
\chapter{QWERTYUIOP}
\section{XYZXYZXYZXYZ}
\subsection{xyxyzxyzxyzxyz}

\end{document}
```

[image]