# Changing TOC font to Helvetica with titlesec

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc

I'm writing a template for my university's phd theses in a `book` document class, but I keep getting stuck at how to implement the `titlesec` package.

I've managed to remove the 'Chapter 1' numbering, but as a beginner I'm still at a loss for how to force entire TOC (including heading) and Headings throughout the document to Helvetica whilst maintaining Times New Roman for the main text. Is it possible to have the dots for deeper headings also for higher levels, such as chapters?

Do I have to use the `titletoc` package for this?

I've attached a reproducible sample.

```
\documentclass{book}
%toc formatting
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%Removes Chapter numbering
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Large\bfseries} % format
  {}                % label
  {0pt}             % sep
  {\huge}           % before-code

%Sets fonts.
\usepackage{pslatex}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A very long journey}
\section{Section A}
\lipsum

\section{Section B}
\lipsum

\chapter{A second journey}
\section{The second Section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very partial answer. Below is a revised version of your MWE which sets chapter titles in Helvetica but which failed to set the ToC in Helvetica.

```
% helveticaprob.tex  SE 614084

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%toc formatting
\usepackage{tocloft} % fiddle with the ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep} % use dotted leader for chapters

%Removes Chapter numbering
\titleformat{\chapter}
%  {\Large\bfseries} % format
  {\Large\bfseries\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}} % format using Helvetica
  {}                % label
  {0pt}             % sep
  {\huge}           % before-code

\begin{comment}
% this produces an error
\titleformat{\chapter*}
%  {\Large\bfseries} % format
  {\Large\bfseries\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}} % format
  {}                % label
  {0pt}             % sep
  {\huge}           % before-code
\end{comment}

%Sets fonts
%%\usepackage{pslatex}  % produces warnings
\usepackage{mathptmx} % times font


\begin{document}
\bgroup
\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}  % set ToC in Helvetica, but it doesn't
\tableofcontents
\egroup

\chapter{A very long journey}
\section{Section A}
\lipsum

\section{Section B}
\lipsum

\chapter{A second journey}
\section{The second Section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The ToC uses `\chapter*` for it's title but I couldn't get this set with Helvetica. I think that if you can get all your division titles (chapters, sections, etc) set in Helvetica then your ToC could be set in Helvetica.

I used the `tocloft` package to add a dotted leader to the chapter entries in the ToC. Read the manual for more information.

I wish you well with your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a lower-level approach might get a further half-step of the way there, if the TOC picks up the current font.

Wrap the `\tableofcontents` command in a font command.

With `fontspec`:

Book Antiqua (in blue):

[image: blue]

FreeSans (in red):

[image: red]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec} 

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\ffonta{Book Antiqua}[Colour=blue,Scale=2]
\newfontfamily\ffontl{FreeSans}[Colour=red,Scale=1.5]
\newcommand{\myfont}{\ffontl}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\contentsname{{\myfont Contents}}
{\myfont
\tableofcontents
}

\section{Text A}
x
\section{Text B}
y
\section{Text C}
z

\end{document}
```

With legacy fonts:

Uncial (`uncl`):

[image: uncial]

Helvetica (`phv`):

[image: helvetica]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\myfont}{\color{violet}\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}%uncl=uncial, phv=helvetica

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\contentsname{{\myfont\fontsize{20}{18}\selectfont Contents}}
{\myfont\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont
\tableofcontents
}

\section{Text A}
x
\section{Text B}
y
\section{Text C}
z

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: using `tocloft` and `titletoc`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261427/font-in-toc-entries